# Is there any way to modify the viewing angle of HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have one question, can we modify or assign any viewing angle to HTML visible tags because when I visited one website https://datatables.net/download/

While I see header of this website the first thought was come in my mind is whether there's any problem with the header?  After scrolling I found the Bottom(footer) as a reciprocal of header and my thought was changed, the guy who developed this site have creative mind, but I found the contents of this site was not visually hatched after that I was think that if there is any way to modify or assign the value of angle by it will hatched, if it will possible then I will create one website which is looks like completely hatched means all tags like div, a, p, span, will render as hatched on screen, and I am now so excited to create about.

I know this is maybe impossible, but I know here on stackoverflow all types of genius available to help so can anyone tell me how it is possible or not 
or is there any way to modify internal structure by JS or something else

**In short I want to create like this image if you don't understand the meaning of hatched line or viewing angle >>** [think of it as a 3 div element and one submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZjZl.png)
thanks.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking (hatched? Viewing angle?), but you can certainly manipulate the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: My first thought is that English is probably not your first language; while that doesn't stop us wanting to help it becomes difficult to help if your question is poorly formed. Is there any chance that you might have a friend, colleague or relative that might be able to help you re-write your question so that we might better understand what you're asking? Also, if it's of help, we do have sites in [Portuguese](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) and [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You could transform each element of the content by CSS. For the website you gave as example this rule would have to be applied:

```
.fw-body .content > * {
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
```

[image: hatchet content]

Answer (score 0):

The sloped edges on the header of the page you noted, can be made with CSS3. Check out [this blog](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2017/design/sloped-edges-with-consistent-angle-in-css/) for an example.